# Cookieless attribute web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

Currently I am using this in my web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="60" />
```

My question is what is the difference between `UseCookies` and `false` in `cookieless` attribute? It is confusing for me.

Comment: Duplicated Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273066/what-are-cookieless-sessions

Comment: Doesn't seem duplicate to me. Where are my 2 modes used in the link you posted?

Comment: Okay, I'll make a properly answer for that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx (2000, written in .NET 1.0)

> Cookieless. The cookieless option for ASP.NET is configured with this
>   simple Boolean setting.

Now, from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx (2005, written in .NET 2.0)

> 1. "UseCookies": As this name implies, the cookieless feature will never be used.
> 2. "UseUri": The cookieless feature will always be used.
> 3. "UseDeviceProfile": Depending on the browser making the request, the cookieless feature may or may not be used. If ASP.NET recognizes
>      that the browser does not support cookies, then the cookieless feature
>      will be used. Technically speaking, the two Boolean variables
>      Request.Browser.Cookies and Request.Browser.SupportsRedirectWithCookie
>      must both be true for ASP.NET to assume that cookies are supported by
>      the browser.
> 4. "AutoDetect": In this setting, ASP.NET attempts to detect whether the browser supports cookies or not. The algorithm is a little
>      complex, and I'll lay it out in pseudo code. (The algorithm is subject
>      to change in future builds).

As we can see, this boolean mode "true" or "false" was probably deprecated

So if "false" and "true" values still work nowdays (for .NET framework 2.0 and above) I guess when you set "false" it assumes that will be used cookies for storing session identifier as **UseCookies** and "true" will assume that you don't want to store cookies as **UseUri**.