# Ajax AutoComplete is not working when Session State is true

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

**Default.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
               <label for="txteno"> Enter Badge No : </label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txteno" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txteno_TextChanged"
                  MaxLength="6" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="0" CompletionInterval="10"  EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="1" TargetControlID="txteno"  
                  ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="true" CompletionListCssClass="AutoExtender" CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoExtenderList" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoExtenderHighlight"  >  
               </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>              

               <label for="txtename"> Name : </label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtename" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>

               <label for="txtnationality"> Designation : </label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtnationality" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"   onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"></asp:TextBox>

               <label for="txtdname"> Nationality : </label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtdname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"></asp:TextBox>

               <asp:Label ID="lblerror" runat="server" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>           
</form>
```

> **No Error** 
>   But not able to load auto complete drop-down, hosted application in IIS 8.0 and  Session State is true

Comment: You might need to add `EnableViewState = "False"` to the TextBox, but that is only a guess.

Comment: Still not not loading auto dropdown only in IIS but when I run from VS 2015 (localhost) that time it is working ..

Comment: 1) You mention IIS 6.2, but as far as I can tell there is no such version. 2) Are you sure that all the code for the autocomplete got uploaded to the server?

Comment: Sorry its IIS 8.0, Yes i am sure all code of lines compiled and uploaded in ISS Server  only thing is, when session state is true URL is showing with some unique code so that is the reason I guess its not loading autocomplete box.

Comment: I guess the request may contains something useful information, I suggest you could try to use f12 develop tool's network to see the autocomplete related ajax request's response.

Comment: "when session state is true URL is showing with some unique code" => in web.config in the `<sessionState>` element it needs `cookieless="false"`. (Although [Cookieless attribute web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19859158/1115360) suggests it should be `cookieless="UseCookies"`.)

Comment: In web.config under which section I have to add cookieless="UseCookies" ?

Comment: You'll get the information faster by using Google, but [How can i set <sessionstate> in web.config?](https://forums.asp.net/t/1231988.aspx?How+can+i+set+sessionstate+in+web+config+)